# How is Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL a document database (non relational) and supports SQL at the same time?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

According to Azure documentation Cosmos DB is a document database (non relational) and at the same time it supoprts SQL, how is that possible ?

<<The Azure Cosmos DB API for NoSQL stores data in ***document format***. It offers the best end-to-end experience as we have full control over the interface, service, and the SDK client libraries. Any new feature that is rolled out to Azure Cosmos DB is first available on API for NoSQL accounts. ***NoSQL accounts provide support for querying items using the Structured Query Language (SQL) syntax***, one of the most familiar and popular query languages to query JSON objects

Comment: It's just a query language. There's no magic to it. Also, the SQL variant in Cosmos DB ins't identical to, say, SQL Server's (it only supports `SELECT`, for instance, requiring SDK/API calls for other operations). To be clear: "SQL" does not equate to "Relational database."

Answer (score -1):

**Azure Cosmos DB** is like a big, flexible storage box where you can keep all sorts of things (data) without worrying about organizing them too strictly. It's part of the NoSQL family because you don't have to follow rigid rules on how you store your stuff.

Now, even though it's super flexible, Cosmos DB also lets you use something called SQL to find and work with your data. SQL is a popular tool many people know from the world of more organized databases, where everything has to be in a certain place.

So, how does it do both? Cosmos DB uses a special version of SQL made just for it. This special SQL lets you search through your flexible, mixed up data easily even if it's not organized in a strict way. It's like being able to ask specific questions (using SQL) to quickly find what you need in your big, flexible storage box (Cosmos DB).

Comment: What do you mean by "do both"? What two things is it doing? It's a document store with a query language, just like every other document store. But it's also not the same as a relational database's SQL language. And it's also not a "big flexible storage box" - it's far more nuanced than that. FYI the question itself is off-topic - best not to answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - you assert that the question is "off topic" but given that the two votes to close it are for a completely inappropriate reason ("Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources") this doesn't seem borne out by the available off topic reasons